# How to convert horizontal ul to vertical on Phones with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a menu made with `ul` and I made it horizontal. every `li` has an icon at the top and a text at the bottom.

```css
    .menu{
      width:800px; margin:0 auto;
    }
    .menu li{
      display: inline;
      list-style: none;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 1.9em;
      padding: 0;
      text-align:center;
    }
    .menu .fa {
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
    }
    .selected {
      color: red;
    }
    .menu li:hover{
      color: red;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-5x selected" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Venue Information</span></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Media</span></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-link fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Social Links</span></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-tags fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Tags</span></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-music fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Events</span></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-glass fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Bottle Service</span></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-cutlery fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Menus</span></li>
</ul>
```

On laptops seems great like this picture[image]

But on mobile phones

[image]

How Can I convert this menu to vertical on mobile phones so it will be responsive?

Note: I know how to use media queries, my question is how to convert the menu code to vertical

Comment: Are you familiar with media queries?

Comment: I know how to use media queries, my question is how to convert the menu code to vertical

Answer (score 0):

You have to start using Media Queries.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

```
.menu li{
  display: block;
}

@media (min-width:768px){

    .menu li{
      display: inline;
    }

}
```

Comment: I know how to use media queries, my question is how to convert the menu code to vertical

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the same styles via @media query:

- Note you would have to tweak some values to optimize view in mobile, for example `.menu`'s `width` to be lower than `414px` or whatever the @media breakpoint is, this way content wouldn't overflow.
- You might also want to set `.fa-5x` to `display: none;` in the query and use a smaller size considering the mobile viewport.

This is just a generic example:

```
@media (max-width: 414px) {
    .menu {
        width: 414px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .menu li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 1.9em;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .menu .fa {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
    }
    .selected {
        color: red;
    }
    .menu li:hover {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the end of your CSS code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
  .menu li{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

and test on a small screen (phone). This is by no means a full answer, it's rather a quick demo of Media Queries in CSS. So make sure you read up on them (One of my favorites tutorials on Media Queries is on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp), check it out.

Best of luck.

Comment: And for the curious minds out there, the code in @Valius79 answer applies a "Mobile First" approach, mine is "Desktop First"